# How to transpose this formulae find the value

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a formulae and I have no idea how to transpose it to get the right answer can someone explain in steps so I know in future how to deal with these questions

F = (nx - n) / R

if
F = 3.75
n = 1
R = 24.31

what is (nx) and how do i get there?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F = \frac{nx-n}{R}$$
$$FR = n(x-1)$$
$$\frac{FR}{n} = x-1$$
$$\frac{FR}{n} + 1 = x$$

First, I multiplied both sides by $R$, and pulled out $n$ from $nx-n$.  Next, I divided both sides by $n$.  Lastly, I added $1$ to both sides.

This isolates $x$, your unknown.

Solving for $nx$ is even quicker:

$$F = \frac{nx-n}{R}$$
$$FR = nx-n$$
$$FR + n = nx$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I John fantastic it looks excellent - nx itself was actually a single variable perhaps I should have named it better.

Comment: Oh, it's $n_x$ (with a subscript)?

Comment: Yeah - One last question if the answer with nx is 1.91 how would that equation change.  I see FR + n = nx I would need to divide FR / 100 + (n),   Feel free to change my question to the subscript.

Comment: If your equation is the same, then if you know three of the four variables -- $F,R,n,n_x$ -- you can find the fourth.  But if you have a different equation then plugging in the numbers will yield a different result.